# Fastest sorting method for k digits and N elements, k <<< N

Tags: c++, sorting

Question: There are n balls, they are labeled 0, 1, 2 and the order is chaotic, I want to sort them from small to large.  Balls:

```
1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, ...
```

We must use the fastest way to solve and cannot use sort() function, I thought many ways like the bubble sort, inset sort, etc. But it is not fast. Is there an algorithm that makes the time complexity is O(logn) or O(n)?

given balls list A[] and length n

```
void sortBalls(int A[], int n)
{
 //code here
}
```

Comment: In chaotic order you have at least O(n), even if the list is already sorted. You have to inspect each element at least once after all.

Comment: Since they're all `0, 1, 2`, you can just loop through a counter of 3 indexes, then recreate the array. This is `O(n)` in time and `O(1)` in memory...!

Comment: Because of the form of the data, I think the optimal algorithm is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the very limited number of item types (`0`, `1`, and `2`), you just count the number of occurrences of each.  Then to print the "sorted" array, you repeatedly print each label the number of times it occurred.  Running time is `O(N)`

```
int balls[N] = {...};  // array of balls: initialized to whatever
int sorted_balls[N];   // sorted array of balls (to be set below)
int counts[3] = {};    //   count of each label, zero initialized array.

// enumerate over the input array and count each label's occurance
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    counts[balls[i]]++;
}

// sort the items by just printing each label the number of times it was counted above
int k = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < counts[j]; x++)
    {
        cout << j << ", ";   // print
        sorted_balls[k] = j; // store into the final sorted array
        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: there are 3 loops, shouldn't the runtime be greater than O(n)?

Comment: @Pkzzz: `2*N` or `3*N` or `100*N` are still `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small number of possible values known in advance, and the value is everything you need to know about the ball (they carry no other attributes), "sorting" becomes equivalent to "counting how many of each value there are". So you generate a histogram - an array from 0 to 2, in your case - go through your values and increase the corresponding count. Then you generate an array of n_0 balls with number 0, n_1 balls with number 1 and n_2 with number 2, and voila, they're sorted.

It's trivially obvious that you cannot go below O(n) - at the very least, you have to look at each value once to count it, and for n values, that's n operations right away.